# Get values from JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP to get a JSON response from a website and then process the response using `json_decode`.  This is my PHP code:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.checkwx.com/taf/LLBG/?format=json");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $headers = [
      'X-API-Key: 555555555'
  ];

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  $json=json_decode($response,true);
  $fulltaf = $json['status']['success']['data']['icao'];
```

This doesn't work.

This is the `JSON` data returned to be processed by `json_decode`:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "icao": "KPIE",
            "observed": "07-03-2017 @ 14:20Z",
            "raw_text": "KPIE 071353Z 13017G23KT 10SM CLR 21\/13 A3031 RMK AO2 SLP262 T02060128",
            "wind_degrees": 130,
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what didn't work?

First problem is that your JSON has a syntax error.  I tried to validate your JSON using http://jsonlint.com and it flagged an extra comma after the 130 for wind_degrees.  Check that actual response doesn't have that comma.  The JSON won't parse properly with the extra comma.

The next problem is that `data` is an array (because its data is enclosed in brackets).  In this example the array only has one element, `[0]`, therefore to access `icao` you need to reference it as I show below.

My guess is that the following line didn't work correctly:

```
    $fulltaf = $json['status']['success']['data']['icao'];
```

Based on the JSON you listed, this line should be the following if you want to retrieve the `icao` member of `data`.

```
    $fulltaf = $json['data'][0]['icao'];
```

The following reference should return `'success'` if you want to test for a successful response.

```
    $json['status']
```